# java: code keeps looping

Tags: java, loops

The below code is giving me a headache: It's supposed to jump out of the do--while loop after replacing all \n's, but it doesn't. Any ideas how to solve this?

```
 public String invoerenTemplate(){
        String templateGescheiden = null;
        String teHerkennenTemplate = Input.readLine();
        String uitvoer = teHerkennenTemplate;

        do {            
            templateGescheiden = teHerkennenTemplate.substring(0, teHerkennenTemplate.indexOf(" "));

            templateGescheiden += " ";

            if (templateGescheiden.charAt(0) == '\\' && templateGescheiden.charAt(1) == 'n')  {
                teHerkennenTemplate = teHerkennenTemplate.replace(templateGescheiden, "\n");
                uitvoer = uitvoer.replace(templateGescheiden, "\n");
            }
            teHerkennenTemplate = teHerkennenTemplate.substring(teHerkennenTemplate.indexOf(" "));

            System.out.println(uitvoer);
            } while (teHerkennenTemplate.length() > 0);
            return uitvoer;

    }
```

EDIT:

I now placed this line: `teHerkennenTemplate.trim();` just beneath my if-statement, but now it gives me a `StringIndexOutOfRange: 0` error at my first line of my if-statement

Comment: What is your termination condition? Will it ever evaluate to `false`?

Comment: i'm substringing 'teHerkennenTemplate' at spaces, so eventually is should be empty

Comment: is it possible that teHerkennenTemplate is stuck on a string with " " (white space), so the line teHerkennenTemplate = teHerkennenTemplate.substring(teHerkennenTemplate.indexOf(" "));
 always have the same effect?

try to add a print to teHerkennenTemplate  after the line above for debug.

Comment: that's it, i added a print line and if my input is: "test \n test \n" it prints: "\n test \n"

Comment: I tried to trim teHerkennenTemplate ervery loop, but it's still not working

Comment: Are you sure the input line contains \\n as a 3 character string, rather than a carriage return character?  Either way, please add an example of the input line.

Comment: @NickHolt : test \n test \n

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed a couple of problems with the above code, although it is difficult to tell why you are taking the approach that you are to the solution.

The main thing I noticed is that your replace statements do NOT remove the `\n` characters

```
teHerkennenTemplate = teHerkennenTemplate.replace(templateGescheiden, "\n");
uitvoer = uitvoer.replace(templateGescheiden, "\n");
```

---

From Java Documentation:

> replace(char oldChar, char newChar):
>
> Returns a new string resulting from replacing all occurrences of oldChar in this string with newChar.

---

So, you are replacing your string `templateGescheiden` with `\n` each time you loop.

Another issue would be the improper shortening of your `teHerkennenTemplate` string each loop, which is causing it not to terminate correctly. It will always shorten from the next space character to the end of the string (inclusive) - meaning it will never be an empty string, but will always have a `" "`.

My advice would be to debug and go step-by-step to see where the shortening and string manipulation is not doing what you want, then evaluate why and modify the code appropriately

Answer (score 0):

There's a variety of things wrong with the code:

- the index of a carriage return is found in the string with `indexOf("\n")`.
- the substring of `teHerkennenTemplate` isn't taking into account that it starts with a space, which cause the loop to continue forever.

The simplest way to do what you want is with a regular expression:

```
"test \n test \n".replaceAll("\n", "")
```

Will return:

```
"test  test "
```

If you're set on using a loop then this will do the same:

```
public static String invoerenTemplate(String teHerkennenTemplate)
{
  StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

  while (teHerkennenTemplate.length() > 0)
  {
    int index = teHerkennenTemplate.indexOf("\n");
    result.append(index > -1 ? teHerkennenTemplate.substring(0, index) : teHerkennenTemplate);

    teHerkennenTemplate = teHerkennenTemplate.substring(index + 1, teHerkennenTemplate.length());
  }

  return result.toString();
}
```